# 500 internal server error while using Django and React

Tags: python, reactjs, django, internal-server-error

I faced some problem using react and django.

When I made a http request to django server, I got 500 Internal Server Error.

My code looks like.

```
urls.py

from usercontrol.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', UserView.as_view(), name="something")
]
```

```
usercontrol/views.py

from http.client import HTTPResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from . models import *
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, AllowAny


# Create your views here.


class UserView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            print ("HELO")
        return HTTPResponse("Hello")
    def post(self, request):
        return HTTPResponse("Hello")
```

```
React Code
axios.get("http://localhost:8000/auth/")
 .then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
 })
 .catch((err) => {});
```

Why do I get 500 Internal Server Error?
Please help me to fix this error.

Comment: Please post the actual message of the error you are getting, and the traceback you're getting from the Django server logs (make sure there isn't anything confidential in what you post though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to install `corsheaders` in django.

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

Also need to add following configuration in `settings.py` and add `corsheaders` in `Installed_apps`

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000", 
    "http://127.0.0.1", 
    "http://localhost:3000", 
    "http://localhost"
]

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*', 
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000", 
    "http://127.0.0.1", 
    "http://localhost:3000", 
    "http://localhost"
]
```

While running react server make sure backend django server is also running.